# I am so new to Laravel/PHP and I cant find the error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a CRM system designed with Lavarel. What I am trying to do is selecting some contacts, clicking on save button (I have to save before exporting as CSV).

However after that when I click on download button my contacts will not export to CSV and I receive this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse::withCookie() 
>   Open: /home/mirjamro/public_html/mr-admin.com/app/filters.php

```
Auth::logout(); return Redirect::to(URL::route('AdminShowLogin')); }
if(Auth::check()){
  $ckname=Auth::getRecallerName(); //Get the name of the cookie, where remember me expiration time is stored
  $ckval=Cookie::get($ckname); //Get the value of the cookie
  return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make($ckname,$ckval,1440)); //change the expiration time
}
});
```

I cant download anything from the server.

Comment: You're calling a `withCookie()` function within `BinaryFileResponse`, but this function hasn't been defined.

Comment: @edi9999 please use proper code blocks when editing a question.

Comment: When asking a question, try to respect other's eyes and brains by using proper language. Re-read the question once or twice as if you were reading it for the first time and say if it will be clear for others to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code from:

```
    return $response->withCookie(Cookie::make($ckname,$ckval,1440));
```

to:

```
    return Response::make($response)->withCookie(Cookie::make($ckname,$ckval,1440));
```